# MacBook Pro appears to be completely dead and the charger is showing only a very dimmed green light

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, startup

After doing a suspend I wasn't able to "revive" my early 2011 MacBook Pro.

- MBP does not respond to: power, long-power, SMC reset or even battery test button.
- the charger is showing a dimmed green when connected (almost invisible in day light)
- the charger does not have any problem (tested)

The computer is still under warranty (only 6 months old).

Comment: Sounds like a hardware failure to me. I'd be taking it in  for repair.

Comment: I'm so happy about it, if I'm not wrong the last thing it did it was some firmware upgrade...

Comment: Could be the magsafe is shot... Google around for symptoms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the absence of a repair shop to run diagnostics, you might try isolating things in the following order:

1. Disconnect all external devices
2. Different power adapter
3. Remove RAM
4. Disconnect / remove the battery and then reset the SMC
5. Disconnect hard drive and optical drive

As you remove items, you remove causes of failure. The mac should still POST and beep if everything listed is taken away from the mac. Often, it's an odd part that is causing a failure of the system to charge or drawing too much power when these isolate the issue. In reality, it's likely the DC in board or main logic board, which means it's good you have warranty to cover that eventuality. Do use prudence in doing the above steps, you don't want to physically damage things and run the risk of warranty service being denied due to external damage or someone not technically capable doing work on your mac.

Even if you don't do all of the steps, you can rule out a few more things than you listed initially in the question. Also, Apple service providers will possibly be able to revert your firmware or at least confirm you have a working firmware install as well as be faster to isolate the cause than most consumers doing the steps listed above as they are set up to do this day in and day out.

Comment: I was a hardware failure, they replaced the battery and the mainboard!

Comment: Awesome - that's good to note. Hopefully the list of steps will help others that have the same symptoms even if their failure involves other parts.